# How to join/add strings in an array object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I've an array which has objects inside it:

```
[
{pointID: 1, pointName: "One" },
{pointID: 2, pointName: "Two" },
{pointID: 3, pointName: "Three" }
]
```

I would like to join all the strings i.e pointName like this : "One-Two-Three"

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Edit 1:

This is what I tried so Far:

```
this.viaPoints.forEach(x=> {      
      var splitted = x.pointName.split(" ");    
      console.log('I5: ',splitted[0].join("-"));
     });
```

The reason I've split is because the string will have extra characters some times like "One - A". So I've used split to remove the extra

Edit 2:
In my case this helped as I mentioned above that to remove extra characters and strings:

```
var permittedValues1 = this.viaPoints.map(value => value.pointName.split(" ")[0]).join("-") ;
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ?? Please always mention what you have already attempted !! "I've a programming problem, solve it for me !!" is not how SO is supposed to be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.map` and `.join` functionalities too. Here `.map` will take the values based upon the key-pointName and `.join` is used to return an array as a string. The elements will be separated by a specified separator (here "-").

```
let array = [
      {pointID: 1, pointName: "One" },
      {pointID: 2, pointName: "Two" },
      {pointID: 3, pointName: "Three" }
      ];
var permittedValues = array.map(value => value.pointName).join("-") ;
```

Comment: If i want to apply join for pointID and pointName at sametime, how should we do.?

Comment: public permittedValues = this.array.map(value => value.pointID.toString().concat(value.pointName)).join("-") ;

Comment: Thank you for your response. I meant to say, I have a table. In the first column I want to display all pointID's with a comma, and in the second column all pointNames,.sameway for the third column...

Comment: Why don't you use the ngFor directive for the above array? like this  <table style="border:1px solid green;">
        <tr *ngFor="let x of array"> 
        <td style="border:1px solid green;">{{x.pointID}},</td>
        <td style="border:1px solid green;">{{x.pointName}}</td>
        <td style="border:1px solid green;">{{x.pointID}} -{{x.pointName}}</td>
        </tr>
        </table>

Comment: I figured it out, This is my solution for the query i have.

   const clusterNames=  this.getpolicies.map(item=>item.cluster_name).join(', ');
  const policyNames = this.getpolicies.map(item => item.templateName).join(', ');
  const policyLabel = this.getpolicies.map(item => item.policy_name).join(', ');
  const policyyml = this.getpolicies.map(item => item.templateYaml);
  const tableEntry = {
    clusterNames,
    policyNames,
    policyLabel,
    policyyml
  }
   this.tableDetails = [...this.tableDetails,tableEntry]

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function to return an array which contains `pointName` for each object in the array and join all value of the return array with `-`.

```js
let data = [
  {pointID: 1, pointName: "One" },
  {pointID: 2, pointName: "Two" },
  {pointID: 3, pointName: "Three" }
]

let result = data.reduce((accumulator, current) => {
    return accumulator.concat(current.pointName);
}, []).join('-');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: `.reduce(... => accumulator.concat(...))` is precisely what `.map` does.